# Spring Boot Return Plain Text without ResponseBody annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to return a plain text message without
@ResponseBody annotation in Spring Boot Controller Method.

normally when I return a string This Gives an Error. (actually it looks for a html file.)

```
@GetMapping("/test/message")
    public String Message() {
        
        return "This is a plain Text";
    }
```

when I use this code, this returns an error

*Error resolving template [This is a plain Text], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [This is a plain Text], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers*

My expected result (without use of responsebody)
***This is a plain Text***

problem of ResponseBody is it only response plain text or html file. I want to controll it mySelf.

Comment: If you don't specify `@ResponseBody`, Spring will try to resolve response as template name. I didn't understand, what's the problem with `@ResponseBody`? You can control response type by `produces` variable of `@RequestMapping` annotation

Comment: @RequestMapping(produces="text")  is it like this?

Comment: For text it should be `@RequestMapping(produces = "text/plain")`. P.S. `@GetMapping` also has this parameter, so you can declare your endpoint as `@ResponseBody @GetMapping("/test/message", produces = "text/plain")`

Comment: tried this ` @GetMapping(value = "/test/message", produces = "text/plain") `  still error exists

Comment: Your question is a bit formulated as an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Do you absolutely want to remove a @ResponseBody annotation, or is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be

```java
@GetMapping("/test/message")
public ResponseEntity<String> Message() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("This is a plain Text", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. with this solution Can I render html tamplate? I want to print plain text and html template within same method by doing if else condition.

Comment: Technically you can render templates and return them as a string, yes. But I can't think of a single situation where you would want actually want this. To do that would be an arhitecture flaw and mixing up multiple responsabilities breaks the S from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: `@GetMapping(value = "/hello2", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody
 public String hello2() {
  ResponseTransfer hello_world = new ResponseTransfer("well hello there2");
  return hello_world.getText();
 }`  -  I have made it work this way as well you can look into produces = MediaType. and look up MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE as an example

Comment: I would like to put focus on the "produces"-value of the `GetMapping`-Annotation. This was the crucial part for me. Thanks @VH

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you annotate your controller using @RestController annotation, then the response can be returned as a plain text. And use @Controller annotation when you want to render it to a template.

```
@Controller
class MyThymeleafController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        return "greeting";//renders a template
    }
}

@RestController
class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";//renders plain text
    }
}
```

https://github.com/faskan/spring-boot-thymeleaf-sample

It would be nice if you could explain the reason on why you would need to render a template or a string in the same method.

Comment: ok. that is good. But rest controller is other thing. I need an extra controller for this. Can it possible with `@Controller` ? Actually I want to show oneline message to user (may be any validation message or warning) and for debugging and I want to do this within same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly take `HttpServletResponse` as a parameter in controller method and write any data in `HttpServletResponse` by setting the contentType or one can use `PrintStream` to directly write output in response object.

```java
public void getData(HttpServletResponse res) {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("url");
    res.setContentType("Any content type");
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}

PrintStream print = new PrintStream(res);
print.write("data");
```